# NativeScript JavaScript modal dialog fails with ViewHierarchy error on iOS

Tags: nativescript

I have a relatively simple modal dialog within a much larger NativeScript JavaScript app which when launched fails with the error message,

```
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/trace/trace.js:166:30: ViewHierarchy: Parent is already presenting view controller. Close the current modal page before showing another one!
```

This works fine on Android but fails consistently on iOS.  The code follows the sample at https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/modal-view. tns doctor shows no errors and all code up to date.  What's stumping me here is figuring out what I can change, as this is the only modal dialog in the entire app.

I'd welcome any ideas.

Edit:

I tried a similar but older app and the same modal dialog works as expected there.  But, it's running 4.2.0 versions of core modules and iOS.

```
✔ Component nativescript has 5.3.2 version and is up to date.
⚠ Update available for component tns-core-modules. Your current version is 4.2.0 and the latest available version is 5.3.1.
⚠ Update available for component tns-android. Your current version is 4.2.0 and the latest available version is 5.3.1.
⚠ Update available for component tns-ios. Your current version is 4.2.0 and the latest available version is 5.3.1.
```

Here's the modal dialog code in question:

```
/**
* Open Modal dialog to select phone number when multiple exist
* @param {object} page 
* @param {object} contact - object returned from getContact 
* @return {object} - Promise, result from selected contact, or null
*/
selectPhone = ((page, contact) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var modalPageModule = "views/phone-select-page";
    var fullscreen = false;

    var slept; // Promise for wait on iOS 

    // Wait briefly on iOS for contacts app to close (admittedly a hack)
    if (page.ios) {
      slept = myutils.sleep(50);
    } else {
      slept = Promise.resolve();
    }

    slept.then(() => {
      page.showModal(  // Ref: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/modal-view
        modalPageModule,
        contact,
        ((response) => { // anonymous closeCallback function
          if (response) {
            resolve(response); // return promise with modified contact
          } else { // (handle back button press on Android)
            reject(response);
          }
        }), // end closeCallback function
        fullscreen
      ); // end page.showModal
    }); // end slept.then
  }); // end return New Promise
}); // end selectPhone
```

Here's the modal dialog itself

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" shownModally="onShownModally" 
  xmlns:dd="nativescript-drop-down">
  <StackLayout class="modal-page">
    <Label class="instructions" textWrap="true" text="Select the phone number to use" />
    <dd:DropDown class="phones" items="{{ phones }}" selectedIndex="{{ phoneIndex }}" hint="Tap here to choose number" />
    <StackLayout class="hr"/>
    <GridLayout columns="*,*" rows="auto">
      <Button class="btn navbtn" col="1" tap="onOkTap" text="OK"/>
    </GridLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

And here's the modal's .js file:

```
var observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");

var closeCallback;  // make modal closeCallback function global 

exports.onShownModally = function (args) {
  const page = args.object;
  var model = new observableModule.fromObject(args.context);
  page.bindingContext = model;
  closeCallback = args.closeCallback;
}

exports.onOkTap = function (args) {
  var page = args.object.page;
  var response = page.bindingContext; // use input context object as response object 
  response.phone = response.phones[response.phoneIndex];
  response.phone = response.phone.substr(response.phone.indexOf(":")).match(/\d/g).join("");
  page.closeModal();
  closeCallback(response);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to show multiple modal windows at a time, launch one from another modal?

Comment: @Manoj - that's what the error message would suggest, isn't it?  But in this case it's just a single modal dialog.  I know code is useful, so here's the parts in question...

Comment: (Code added to original post, as comments are limited)

Comment: Would you mind creating a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be a timing issue returning from the Contacts app on iOS.  That was the reason for this code:

```
// Wait briefly on iOS for contacts app to close (admittedly a hack)
if (page.ios) {
  slept = myutils.sleep(50);
} else {
  slept = Promise.resolve();
}
```

(Alas, I had dealt with this same problem last summer when I originally developed this code.) If I change the delay from 50ms to 750ms, the code works fine.  I'm guessing this is due to changes in {N} 5.  So, it's still a hack, but I can live with it for now.

edit 4/24/2020: I developed a fix for this and created a pull request (#84) for nativescript-contacts.  See [issue #75](https://github.com/firescript/nativescript-contacts/issues/75) for more info.

Comment: Did you find a better solution in the meantime? Im also facing this issue... Puting 800ms timeout usually works but sometime not, so I considered this as a real big hack. Did you open a bug on the nativescript github page? https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript

Comment: @bidou No, I never found a better solution.  I didn't open an issue against NativeScript, as it's not clear to me that's where the problem is.  If you find something better, I'd love to get rid of this hack.

Comment: I just opened a bug here: https://github.com/firescript/nativescript-contacts/issues/75

Comment: I just upgraded to Nativescript 6 and this workaround is not working any more. To make it work again, I had to additionally put a `zone.run({openMyMultipleAddressPopup(); });` inside the `timeout()`